# Bootstrap 4 modal-body bg-color annoying bug with width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My problem is that when i apply a background color to modal-body in a Bootstrap modal the modal-body doesn't get colored 100%.

A approximately 0.2px is left white as shown below.

(Look right side of modal-body)

How it is:
[image]

How it should be:
[image]

I managed to fix that by adding `style="width: calc(100% + 0.2px);"`

So i want to ask why is this happening? And if there is a better way to -perma- fix this bug.

Maybe it has to do with some weird `box-sizing` setting of bootstrap? I really don't have any clue.

[Click here for codepen.](https://codepen.io/megatixos/pen/mZKMWM)

P.S.
If the white line doesn't show in your screen, try to resize the right border of your browser while viewing the codepen.

EDIT:
I use Chrome, on Windows 10 and only Bootstrap and jQuery (latest versions).

EDIT2:
Showcasing the bug using Gyazo GIF:
https://gyazo.com/113cd5a38abdea52ba338039d25e5bff

Comment: Codepen looks fine, I am using Chrome

Comment: Actually cannot reproduce that.  Mac OS, Firefox and Chrome.  Do you have css besides bootstrap ?

Comment: Take a look at my gyazo at my editted post. @brooksrelyt

Comment: Are you looking too hard into this? Not many people resize their browser like this when viewing your content. It's super annoying for devs but users may not notice.. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the correct way to fix this, apparently this was happening because modal-content has by default a border.

Just add `border-0` class to `modal-content` and it should be ok.

[Click for fixed codepen.](https://codepen.io/megatixos/pen/OeEOVy)